# What did you eat or what have you eat?

Tags: do-support, past-vs-past-perfect

If I am asking someone what he got for his birthday, would it be

> "What did you get?"

or

> "What have you got?"

Comment: "What have you eat" is not a correct English. It should be "have you eaten". There's no significant difference between those examples, just the p.perfect version(have you eaten) is more common is BrE, and simple past(did you eat) is more common in AmE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ask someone what was given to them on their birthday

> What did you get?
>   What did you receive?

are the two common questions

> What have you got?

would be incorrect since the receiving is in the past.
Also be aware that

> What have you got? = What do you have?

which is a different meaning then you might have intended.

Answer (score 0):

"What did you eat?"

OR

"What have you eaten?"

BOTH are correct and mean the same.